# Issue with bigtable mutateRow() call to update row. The update operation is not working as expected without any errors

Tags: scala, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am trying to update an existing row with key "2023-09-25" in my bigtable table.
The mutateRow() call succeeds, but I don't see update happening. The row key "2023-09-25" still holds previous value even after the below call. Note, I am able to add a new row using below code,but not able to update. Can anyone help? thanks

```
 try{
  val rowMutation = RowMutation.create("my_table_123", "2023-09-25").setCell("info", "table_name", "b_sad_201")
  println(bigtableClient.mutateRow(rowMutation))
}
catch {
  case e: Exception => {
      e.printStackTrace()
    false
  }
}
```

I am trying this in a scala app

Comment: Can you check this [Article](https://medium.com/@philipp.schmiedel/how-to-update-row-keys-in-google-big-table-4db0c85e3be#:~:text=So%20if%20we%20can%27t,our%20changed%20row%20key%20design).